# Protractor locator issues

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

My goal is to pull the `css width` of a particular element.

The actual jQuery command I use in Chrome console works well :

```
$('div-grid-directive[grid-name="SAT"] .qMinus1_resize_expand').first().css('width');
"0px"
```

However, running Protractor in a Win 7 cmd prompt, I'm getting the following error:

```
Message:
  Failed: element(...).first is not a function
```

The error points to my objects page **topNav.icons.page.js**, in `this.getQMinus1Column` :

```js
module.exports = function(){        
    this.clickExpandRowsIcon = function(){
        $('.resize-btns > .glyphicon.glyphicon-resize-horizontal').click();
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
    };
    this.getQMinus1Column = function(){            
        return element(by.css('div-grid-directive[grid-name="SAT"] .qMinus1_resize_expand')).first();
    };
};
```

and my SAT.spec.js file :

```js
var IndexPage = require('./pageObjects/index.page.js');
var TopNavBar = require('./pageObjects/topNav.icons.page.js');

describe('Testing the Sales & Trading Top Nav grid icons', function(){
    var indexPage = new IndexPage();
    var topNavBar = new TopNavBar();
    
    beforeEach(function () {
        indexPage.get();   // Launches app !!        
    });
    describe('Clicking on the Expand Rows icon', function () {
  
        it('Should horizontally expand previous quarters qMinus1 thru qMinus6', function () {        
            topNavBar.clickExpandRowsIcon();
            var elem = topNavBar.getQMinus1Column();

            expect(elem).getCssValue().indexOf('width: 5px;').not.toBe('-1');            
  });
    });
    
});
```

So before I even try to get the `css width` attribute, I'm struggling to return `first()`, using this format:

```
return element(by.css('MY-CSS')).first();
```

Do I have too much going on in this line, or perhaps the wrong syntax for Protractor ?

```
 return element(by.css('div-grid-directive[grid-name="SAT"] .qMinus1_resize_expand')).first();
```

Again, the same syntax works using jQuery in console tools, so the CSS select is correct.

Advice is greatly appreciated here...

regards,
Bob

Comment: This problem inspired me to have an ESLint rule that would catch these kind of problems early (very convenient if tied with ide like webstorm - you would see the warning right after writing this code): https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/55.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) , `element` does not return a collection of objects to call `first` method in it.

Probably you might want to use [element.all(locator)](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)

Comment: Please also see my `SAT.spec.js` example above where I receive the `elem` var from `this.getQMinus1Column `.

Comment: I can get the css width as follows : `element.all(by.css('MY-SELECTOR')).first()
            .getCssValue("width");`